# How can I have a line above the text c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics

I'm working in C# with Visual S. 2013, and I also have a licence for Infragistics 2015.
In my grid, I have a text label with some text, well.
I want to put a line above the text.
Like this :

### [image]

But I do not know how to proceed...

Many thanks.

Comment: How can you do that in MSWord?

Comment: @dotctor - what's MSWord got to do with it? I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a new class derived from `Label`. I think that code is self-explanatory.

```
class LabelWithLine : Label
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, 0, this.Width, 0);
    }
}
```

Rebuild your solution. Now `LabelWithLine` should appear in toolbox and you can put on form.

[image]

Comment: That's nice ! Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit from `Label` and override the `OnPaint` event:

```
    public class TopBorderLabel : Label
    {
           protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
           {
             base.OnPaint(e);
             ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle,
                                          Color.White, 0, ButtonBorderStyle.None,
                                          Color.Black, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                                          Color.White, 0, ButtonBorderStyle.None,
                                          Color.White, 0, ButtonBorderStyle.None);
           } 
    }
```

This basically says, in plain English, "whenever we paint (i.e. WinForms presents) the control (label), paint it as you would (`base.OnPaint(e)`) but also draw a border around it. We pass in `white, 0, None` for all borders other than the top, which will be black and 2 pixels thick.

### EDIT

OP, I'll leave my answer as it is, as it's still feasible - but I think you'll find Anton's answer is most elegant here as I *do* have to pass a fair few redundant parameters into the `DrawBorder` method.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, it helps me :)

Answer (score 0):

I would Extend it even more so it look professional control.

```
    public class LabelWithLine : Label
    {
        private Color lineColor;
        private DashStyle dashStyle;
        private bool isLineVisible;
        /// <summary>
        ///set browseable and group by category in propery browser
        /// </summary>
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Line")]
        public Color LineColor 
        { 
            get { return lineColor; } 
            set { lineColor = value; this.Invalidate(); } 
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Line")]
        public DashStyle DashStyle { get{return dashStyle;}
            set { dashStyle = value; this.Invalidate(); }
        }
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Line")]
        public bool IsLineVisible { get{return isLineVisible;}
            set { isLineVisible = value; this.Invalidate(); }
        }

        public LabelWithLine()
        {
            lineColor = Color.Black;
            dashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
            isLineVisible = true;

        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            if (isLineVisible)
            {
                Pen p = new Pen(LineColor);
                p.DashStyle =   this.DashStyle;
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, 0, 0, this.Width, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the useage

```
labelWithLine1.LineColor = Color.Blue;
labelWithLine1.IsLineVisible = true;
labelWithLine1.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid;
```